# Traefik error adding file watcher file not found

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I am working with docker compose.
I am running some containers with traefik, whoami and authelia.

```
cat docker-compose.yml

---
version: '3'

services:
traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.example.com`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.tls.options=default'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=authelia@docker'
    command:
      - '--api'
      - '--log=true'
      - '--log.level=DEBUG'
      - '--providers.docker=true'
      - '--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false'
      - '--providers.file.filename=/etc/traefik/certificates.yml'
      - '--entrypoints.http=true'
      - '--entrypoints.http.address=:80'
      - '--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=https'
      - '--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https'
      - '--entrypoints.https=true'
      - '--entrypoints.https.address=:443'
    ports:
      - 8080:80  # Web
      - 1443:443 # https
    volumes:
      - /my_dir/traefik:/etc/traefik
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

authelia:
    image: authelia/authelia
    container_name: authelia
    volumes:
      - /my_dir/authelia:/config
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.authelia.rule=Host(`authelia.example.com`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.authelia.entrypoints=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.authelia.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.authelia.tls.options=default'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.authelia.forwardauth.address=http://authelia:9091/api/verify?rd=https://authelia.example.com'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.authelia.forwardauth.trustForwardHeader=true'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.authelia.forwardauth.authResponseHeaders=Remote-User,Remote-Groups,Remote-Name,Remote-Email'
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      ## In production the healthcheck section should be commented.
      disable: true

whoami:
  image: traefik/whoami
  container_name: whoami
  labels:
    - 'traefik.enable=true'
    - 'traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.example.com`)'
    - 'traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=https'
    - 'traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls=true'
    - 'traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.options=default'
    - 'traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=authelia@docker'
```

I was getting this error:

```
docker compose logs traefik

traefik  | time="2023-11-28T18:36:20+01:00" level=info msg="Starting provider *file.Provider"
traefik  | time="2023-11-28T18:36:20+01:00" level=debug msg="*file.Provider provider configuration: {\"watch\":true,\"filename\":\"/my_dir/traefik/certificates.yml\"}"
traefik  | time="2023-11-28T18:36:20+01:00" level=error msg="Cannot start the provider *file.Provider: error adding file watcher: no such file or directory"
traefik  | time="2023-11-28T18:36:20+01:00" level=info msg="Starting provider *traefik.Provider"
```

So I changed the providers.file.filename to `- '--providers.file.filename=/etc/traefik/certificates.yml'`.

But I am getting this error now:

```
traefik  | time="2023-11-29T11:01:22+01:00" level=info msg="Starting provider *file.Provider"
traefik  | time="2023-11-29T11:01:22+01:00" level=debug msg="*file.Provider provider configuration: {\"watch\":true,\"filename\":\"/etc/traefik/certificates.yml\"}"
traefik  | time="2023-11-29T11:01:22+01:00" level=error msg="Error while building configuration (for the first time): yaml: line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context" providerName=file

cat /my_dir/traefik/certificates.yml

---
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /etc/traefik/certs/public.crt
      keyFile: /etc/traefik/certs/private.pem


ls -la /my_dir/traefik/certs

-rw-r--r--. 1 user grp 1679 Nov 29 10:48 private.pem
-rw-r--r--. 1 user grp 1143 Nov 29 10:48 public.crt
```

Solution:

Edited file /my_dir/traefik/certificates.yml and added the missing ":" after the certificates entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your compose file, you have:

```
    volumes:
      - /my_dir/traefik:/etc/traefik
```

Recall that the syntax of entries in the `volumes` list is `HOST_PATH:CONTAINER_PATH`, so you are mounting host directory `/my_dir/traefik` inside the container as `/etc/traefik`. When you set:

```
      - '--providers.file.filename=/my_dir/traefik/certificates.yml'
```

That path doesn't exist inside the container.

Either you have the parameters of the `volumes` entry in the wrong order, or you need to point `providers.file.filename` at `/etc/traefik/certificates`.

Comment: ok, so if I point it to /etc/traefik/certificates.yml, than I also have to place the certifcates files (cert.crt, key.pem) inside the container?
I am not sure how it was done in here: https://github.com/authelia/authelia/blob/v4.37.5/examples/compose/local/traefik/certificates.yml I guess everything was placed inside ./traefik folder which was mapped to /etc/traefik

Comment: It looks like I had an issue with missing ":" after certificates in the certificates.yml file. Solved it. Thanks for your help